# About “Analysis complete” listing in PhpStorm 2019.2.3

Tags: phpstorm

Using vuejs in PhpStorm 2019.2.3 I see “Analysis complete” listing at right top corner of my php file :
https://prnt.sc/tfajtc

1. Can I open all these warnings in some dialog pager with possibility to move to it?
2. as this file if library and contains of methods which are mostly used from other parts of the app
   if there is a way to set mark to these methods not mark it as “Unused element”
3. If there is a way to distinguish runner at right scroller, as in some cases I hardly can see it.
   Maybe ser blue/red color to it?

Thanks!

Comment: 1) Use `Code | Inspect Code` -- it will list ALL results in dedicated tool window. 2) If it's a library class (your own code) ... then you should have used those functions/classes/etc somewhere in your actual project or Unit tests (you do tests for your code, right?). In any case: you can disable specific inspections for certain files: just go to that inspection, create custom scope where you do not need that inspection and set it up right there. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/code-inspection.html

Comment: Thanks. Can I change color  of runner at right scroller? I am under kubuntu 18

Comment: What do you mean by "runner"? The strips/marks on the scroll bar that represent the issues? They can be configured yes, just check the `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme | General | Errors and Warnings` -- look at "Error stripe mark" option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In the upcoming 2020.2, you will be able to view the list of warnings and errors in the current file in a separate tool window (**Problems view**) by clicking the Inspections Widget in the upper right corner.
   See https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/06/intellij-idea-2020-2-eap4-problems-view-improved-git-actions-dialogs-and-more/, *Problems View*
2. by runner, do you mean a scrollbar? Starting from version 2019.2.3, **Use contrast scrollbars** flag is added to **Settings | Appearance&Behavior | Appearance | Accessibility** to make your scrollbars more visible. If this option is not enough, and you still would like to alter the scrollbar colors, please vote for [IDEA-222263](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-222263)